# Restricting user from selecting dates other than in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I'm making a conference room booking system as a part of a college project. I'm using jQuery UI's datepicker to allow the user to enter the date. I have kept a restriction on the booking date, that allows users only to book a room minimum 6 days before and maximum 30 days before the actual booking date of the conference.

I have been able to implement that after reading the datepicker API, but since it is a text field, users are able to manually type in the dates as well. So if today is November 20, users can only book for dates between November 26 and December 20. I've put that in the datepicker, but users can still manually type in, say 2013-11-20, and get away with it (Until they are caught by php in the next page, of course.)

I want to write a code in javascript that checks the date and calculates whether it falls in a certain range or not.

Important snippets from my code:

```
    <form action="#" method="post" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <input type="text" name="dateP" id="dateP" placeholder="DATE" required style="margin-right:40px;padding:5px;width:75px;">
    <input id="fromP" type="number" name="fromP" min="0800" max="2000" step="100" placeholder="FROM" required style="padding:5px;">hrs
    <input id="toP" type="number" name="toP" min="0900" max="2100" step="100" placeholder="TO" required style="padding:5px;">hrs<br>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="PROCEED" style="border-color:#13c5ff;color:#13acd9;padding:5px;margin:30px;">
    </form>
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dateP').datepicker({ minDate: +6, maxDate: +30, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", showAnim: "fadeIn"});
    });
```

So by using pure javascript, I can get current date and add 6 or 30 to it to get my required range. But how do i compare it with the date that is generated in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' from jQuery UI?

P.S. I need to keep the format in yyyy-mm-dd because that's the format in my database as well.

Comment: input type=date will help in a lot of places. probably everywhere that number types work... you can also use the pattern attribute to validate the value of an input.

Comment: I know, but the datepicker provided in jQueryUI seemd more appealing, and it was so much easier to customize it in terms of functionality.
Example: Restricting the datepicker to a only a certain range of dates.
I don't know if html5's datepicker has a feature to restrict date range.

Comment: min and max specify restrictions upon the value of an input (including dates), but it looks like you knew that already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/`. However, you'll also need to test against this regex on the server side, as anyone can send whatever they want to the server regardless of client-side validation.